# Can I Return Back to the Destination Airport after I Diverted to the Destination Alternate?

Tags: commercial-aviation, airline-operations, pilots

Can I Return Back to the Destination Airport after I Diverted to the Destination Alternate (while enroute to the destination alternate)?

I highly appreciate an answer with reference please.

Comment: Can you please explain why you even need to ask this question? Why do you think it would not be allowed or would cause a problem?

Answer (score 3):

There are no regulations in the US that state you must land at a particular airport. It will be even more difficult to find one that says you can return to your original destination after announcing or performing a diversion. There are only regulations stating that you have to list a destination airport on an IFR flight plan. And, that there are certain situations when you must list one or more alternate destinations on an IFR flight plan.

VFR flight plans are not required in the US. Even if you file a VFR flight plan, ATC will not be made aware of your flight plan unless it is not closed prior to half an hour after your ETA. In which case, only VFR aircraft on VFR Flight Following will be tracked by ATC. The pilot can cancel a flight plan (IFR or VFR) or flight following at any time that the pilot is in VMC, entering Class G airspace or landed. Otherwise, you must fly your filed IFR flight plan all the way to your clearance limit or your alternate (once you have informed ATC of your diversion). But, you may also amend your flight plan or Flight Following at any time.

Case in point. I have diverted to an airport just to take an unplanned bathroom break. Before diverting, I informed  ATC of the diversion as well as requesting to keep my flight plan and transponder (squawk) code. When returning to controlled airspace, I was able to continue onto my original destination.

Another example of continuing on to your original airport after diverting is when the diversion airport is en route to your original airport. Having an alternate airport planned that is halfway to your original airport gives the pilot a convenient out or Plan B if the weather ahead starts turning hazardous. If the weather improves before you reach your alternate, you can continue onto your original (after informing ATC if on an IFR flight plan or Flight Following).

Comment: To be clear: the only way ATC will "become aware" of your filed VFR flight plan is if Flight Service calls us to ask if we happen to know where you are. We don't have any way of looking at it without calling FSS ourselves. You can cancel an IFR flight plan or VFR flight following with ATC directly; to close a VFR flight plan you need to call FSS.

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no regulation saying you can't return to the original aiport from your diversion airport because it would make no sense. There's no reference to give on this because there's nothing in the regulations that is specific to this situation. There's no reason to prevent you from going back to a primary, and every reason to allow it as the conditions that make you go to an alternative may change and make the original more preferable for safety or other reasons. A couple of examples:

- Changing weather: the primary may be below minimums, so you divert. Conditions change at the primary, making it a safer choice
- Temporary closure: you arrive at the primary to find it's been temporarily closed due to an incident, objects on the runway or something like that. You divert, then find out your primary is open again. Going back to the primary is convenient for you and your passengers

The limiting factor is fuel, if you have enough fuel to get to the alternative and back with plenty of contingency then by all means do it if the situation warrants it.